# Taking specific DataFrame row values and moving them to another new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
Column1  Column2
'a'      'b'
'amount' '$d'
'e'      'f'
'amount' '$g' 
...
```

I created a new column 'Column3', where I would like to take the values of $d, $g, etc. (any value that is directly right to a value 'amount') and move them to Column 3, while also getting rid of value 'amount':

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
a        b        $d
e        f        $g
...
```

What would be the best way to move these values to Column3 and remove 'amount' values?

EDIT: Made the values more specific to the question.

Comment: So, basically, you are shifting `d` and `g` to the previous row here. What should happen if `Column1` contains consecutive values `c`? I mean: from your example, suppose that "e" is also a "c". Where do we leave "d, f, g", all next to "b", as we now only have one row left after getting rid of all the "c" rows? Or are you positive that this never happens?

Comment: @ouroboros1 I've cleaned the data first so that never happens. For the purposes of this question, c will almost always immediately follow an a / e type of row. If you want me to fill more specific values so the question makes more sense, I can do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

- Create a boolean series with `True` where "Column1" equals "amount"([`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)).
- Apply [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to "Column2" to get values next to "amount", and use [`df.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to shift the result one row up.
- Next, we add the series to the `df` with [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), and select from the `df` using the inverse (`~`) of the boolean series.
- Chain [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for a "clean" index.

```
m = df['Column1'].eq('amount')
res = df.assign(Column3=df['Column2'].where(m).shift(-1))[~m].reset_index(drop=True)

res

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0       a       b      $d
1       e       f      $g
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)/[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) :

```
out = df[df["Column1"].ne("amount")].join(df["Column2"].rename("Column3").shift(-1))
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0       a       b      $d
2       e       f      $g
```

Comment: **NB** : This assumes that the `Column1` has a pattern: *not amount -> amount -> not amount* ..

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it:

- Select values from `Column2` that you want to move to a new column
- Create a new df, omitting rows where `["Column1"] != "c"`, and assign the pre-selected values to a new column
- (optional) reset index if you want to

Example:

```
# Pre-select values you want to move from `Column2`
data_to_move = df[df['Column1'] == 'c']['Column2'].values

# Drop rows where 'Column1' equals 'c', assigned pre-selected data to a new column
reshaped_data = df[df['Column1'] != 'c'].copy().reset_index(drop=True)
reshaped_data['Column3'] = data_to_move
reshaped_data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean mask:

```
m = df['Column1'] == 'amount'
df = df[~m].assign(Amount=df.loc[m, 'Column2'].values).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Column1 Column2 Amount
0       a       b     $d
1       e       f     $g
```